# Shell not finding binary when attempting to execute it (it's _definitely_ there)

Tags: shell

I have a specific set of binaries installed at:

```
~/.GutenMark/binary/<binaries...>
```

These were previously working correctly, but for seemingly no reason when I attempt to execute them the shell claims not to find them:

```
james@anubis:~/.GutenMark/binary$ ls -al
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james 2979036 2009-05-10 13:34 GUItenMark
...
-rwxrwxrwx 1 james james   76952 2009-05-10 13:34 GutenMark
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 james james   10156 2009-05-10 13:34 GutenSplit
...
james@anubis:~/.GutenMark/binary$ ./GutenMark
bash: ./GutenMark: No such file or directory
james@anubis:~/.GutenMark/binary$
```

I've tried to isolate the cause of this, with no success.  The same happens with zsh, bash, and sh (all giving their appropriate `file not found` error -- this is definitely not a strange output from the binary itself).  The same happens either as user `James` or as `root`.  Nor is it directory specific; if I move the whole directory installation, or just a single binary, to anywhere else, the same happens when attempting to execute it.  The same even happens when I put the directory in $PATH and just execute "GutenMark".  It also happens when I execute it from a script (I've tried Python's commands module -- though this appears to just call sh).

The problem appears to be specific to the binaries themselves, yet they appear to never actually get executed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `file *` show?

Comment: Another good point, but nope.  The binary `Gutenmark` is:

ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped

Comment: (I should note I meant `GutenMark`, not `Gutenmark`, above.)

Comment: If this is a helpful diagnostic, a new PID is shown before the error if i fork it: `./GutenMark &`.

Comment: I've got around to trying the same binaries on a different system (using `scp`), and they work as expected there -- i.e., as they were working originally on this system.

The saga continues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are trying to run a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit system or vice versa?
And the same question for any libraries used by these executables.

Or are any used libraries now missing?

Comment: It's a 32-bit binary and a 64-bit system.  The same, presumably for all libraries that came with the package.  This is probably not the issue as I've already had the binaries running on this system, and to my knowledge no libraries have been removed since the last successful run.

Comment: ARGH.  Sorry, the problem is now solved, and you were right: libraries **had** been removed.

When the system was fscked around with yesterday by SOMEONE attempting to install flash-player, some low-level libraries were removed.  It's presumably one of the following, that I've just installed:

ia32-libs lib32gcc1 lib32stdc++6 lib32v4l-0 lib32z1 libc6-i386

Thanks to everyone for help with a problem that wasn't completely described.

Answer (score 0):

Is GutenMark (at 76592 bytes) not actually a *binary*, but a *script* starting with a !# line which defines the program which executes the script?

If that line defined a non-existent program, you would see a 'not found' error message.

Comment: A good point, but no:

    james@anubis:~/.GutenMark/binary$ cat GutenMark | head --bytes=200
    ELF4�(4 (44�4�������   ��I �james@anubis:~/.GutenMark/binary$

Comment: A related possibility, though pretty far-fetched, is that `GutenMark` detects the type of shell that is running it, then using it to find a non-existent file.